# WSPBuilder for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, migration

Have anybody used WSPBuilder for SharePoint 2013? What changes should be done to move WebParts from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSPBuilder doesn't support SharePoint 2013

Comment: There are some related discussions on the codeplex WSPBuilder web site. Seems somebody has modified the source code to work with SP2013. Relevant post here: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/discussions/404783

Comment: it's not official

Comment: Yes I know, just adding that in case someone wants to give it a try. That said, if I had the option I would wait for a new version of CKSDev (or see if I can mod it and send the dev team my changes).